# Accordeon with li parents with border radius

Tags: html, inheritance, css

Im trying to make a jquery accordeon where the parents LI have a border radius, this border radius have to be only applied to that parent wrapping the whole li but not anything that its inside and the inside elements have a proper margin and different styles, the thing is as much as i have tried to give exclusive styles to the ul, and li elements inside the LI parents they inherite the border radius and styles from the parent LI.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Dades de contacte</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>bbva</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>i presentacions</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>servei contingència catsalut</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>comunicats</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><span>29 Octubre 2013</span></a>    
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><span>18 Octubre 2013</span></a>    
            </li>
        </ul>   
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>consultat</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Here's the HTML and the CSS
http://jsfiddle.net/vwyv6/

You can realize the problem in the sub-list i want those to have complete different styles and not wrapped by the border radius, i want the rounded corners to just show on the parent LI.

Here's what im trying to accomplish:
[Image](http://postimg.org/image/s636wobw9/)

Any help will be REALLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you really needing is some class in your HTML to help you style it

For instance

HTML

```
<ul class="parent">
    <li><a href="#"><span>Dades de contacte</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>bbva</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>i presentacions</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>servei contingència catsalut</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>comunicats</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><span>29 Octubre 2013</span></a>    
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><span>18 Octubre 2013</span></a>    
            </li>
        </ul>   
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>consultat</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul,li,a {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        list-style: none;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        line-height: 1;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 1em;
        position: relative;
}

a {line-height: 1.3;}

.parent >li {
    background: #ddeaed;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
    border-radius:10px;
    }

ul>li>a {
        font-size: 1em;
        color: #008ba9;
        display: block;
}

.parent >li>a:hover {
    background: #008ba9;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
    border-radius:10px;
}     

ul>li>a>span {
    display: block;
    padding: 12px 10px;
}   


ul  ul > li  span {
    background: blue;
}

ul>ul>li {
    background: white;  
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;}

ul>ul>li>a {display: block;}

ul>ul>li>a:hover {
    background: white;
    color: blue;
}
```

Notice that I replaced some ul by the class name

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vwyv6/1/)

Comment: Thanks a lot but the problem of the border radius still exist. what i need is that the border-radius on the parent LI wrap just the parent LI but no the sublist inside (you can notice that the border is not complete on the parent LI with a sublist). I need to give the sublist a margin top with any borders.

Comment: I have updated the JSFiddle, notice that when i give the sublist a margin top you can realize that the parent LI is filling the space with its background color and the border radius is not wrapping the whole parent Li. http://jsfiddle.net/vwyv6/2/

Comment: There is no way to avoid the li filling all the space. May be you want to set the background only to the span (as in the hover state)?

Comment: Hey vals i got it, besides adding a class to the main <UL> i gave the border-radius to the <A> tag inside the parent <LI> instead of the <LI> itself, that way the <LI> becomes just a container without any style (well maybe just margins or paddings). Thanks a LOT !